# How do I write a foreach loop that checks how many times a user bought a specific item in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, foreach

I'm using this code to generate an iframe if a customer has bought product 13372 and it works great:

```
<?php
// Get the current user data:
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID; // Get the user ID
$customer_email = $user->user_email; // Get the user email
// OR
// $customer_email = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_email', true ); // Get the user billing email

// The conditional function (example)
// IMPORTANT: $product_id argument need to be defined
$product_id = 13372;
if( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id ) ) {
    echo "You have additional listings!"; 
    //iFrame goes here 
} else {
    echo "You have no additional listings.";
}
?>
```

Now I need to modify this to check how many times a user bought product ID 13372 and output that many number of iframes. If bought 3 times, output 3 iframes. I'm assuming a foreach loop, but what I've tried doesn't work. I followed this post: [How to check how many times a product has been bought by a customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280692/how-to-check-how-many-times-a-product-has-been-bought-by-a-customer)

But the example it doesn't return anything for me, not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. We're looping through each completed shop order of a specific customer and putting all IDs of purchased products into an array. We then loop through that array to see how many times a specific ID appears. We store that value in a `$count` variable, which is used to determine how many times to output an iframe.

I've commented the code and made function and variable names as clear as possible.

```php
<?php
function so58032512_get_product_purchase_quantity( $product_id ) {
    // Array to hold ids of all products purchased by customer
    $product_ids = [];

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );

    // Loop through each of this customer's order
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $items = $order->get_items();

        // Loop through each product in order and add its ID to $product_ids array
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $id = $item['product_id'];
            array_push( $product_ids, $id );
        }
    }

    // Variable to count times an ID exists in the $product_ids array
    $count = 0;

    // Loop through all of the IDs in our $product_ids array
    foreach ( $product_ids as $key => $value ) {
        // Every time the ID that we're checking against appears in the array
        if ( $value == $product_id ) {
            // Increment our counter
            $count ++;
        }
    }

    // Return the counter value that represents the number of times the
    // customer bought a product with our passed in ID ($product_id)
    return $count;
}

// Get the current user data:
$user           = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id        = $user->ID; // Get the user ID
$customer_email = $user->user_email; // Get the user email

// IMPORTANT: $product_id argument need to be defined
$product_id = 13372;
if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id ) ) {
    $x = 1;
    $number_of_iframes_to_show = so58032512_get_product_purchase_quantity( $product_id );
    echo 'The customer bought product with ID ' . $product_id . ' ' . $number_of_iframes_to_show . ' time(s).<br>';
    while ( $x <= $number_of_iframes_to_show ) {
        echo "<br>Here's an iframe!<br>";
        $x ++;
    }
} else {
    echo "You have no additional listings.";
}
?>
```